# Why does a bias voltage induce a changing depletion region in a pn junction instead of just creating more current?

Tags: electromagnetism, semiconductor-physics

I am having trouble conceptualizing how a bias voltage for a pn junction creates depletion region differences instead of just inducing a current.

Take a reverse bias for an example. The depletion region would increase, stopping current flow. But instead of that happening, why doesn't the voltage source just make electrons flow through the p-material, travelling through the holes, and then the electrons jump across the border and just travel through the n-material (like normally through metal)?

A pn junction when its diffused, is always at equilibrium. Since there are no counteracting forces, why doesn't the pn junction just behave like one semiconductor and have electrons flow through it?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65360/discussion-on-question-by-goldname-why-does-a-bias-voltage-induce-a-changing-dep).